# Conditional formatting using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to apply a set of conditional rules based upon formulas, the formulas work within a worksheet but not when using conditional formatting.

The formula checks to see whether a date is between a set range and also whether a specific cell is a certain value. See below for details.

Anything over 40 from cell C6 should be red:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6>40,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Anything between 30 and 40 should be amber:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6>30,Sheet2!$C$6<=40,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Anything below 30 should be green:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$6<=30,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","3"))>=Sheet2!$B$6),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Some example data can be seen below:

```
        A           B              C        D
                    start date     days     Finish date
6       January     01/01/2015     30       12/02/2015
```

Comment: You should not need the `IF()` wrapper. Just the `AND()` statement

Comment: Which range are you applying the formatting to?

Comment: Could you show an example of your data and what you are expecting.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have added example data in the question. The letters above the data show column letters whilst the number shows the row number so for example C6 = 30 in the example. What I am expecting is that on another sheet the conditional formatting will show a block of red between a specific set of dates, almost like a calander

Comment: @ScottCraner I emphasize, the pattern `=IF(x, True, False)` seems to be proliferating like a worm recently. It's making me sick :(

Comment: Just to clarify, in Sheet1 you have a row with dates `2015-01-01`, `2015-01-02`, ..., `2015-12-31`. Then you want to color the range of dates starting at `B6` and ending at `D6` in the color determined by `C6`?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Yes I have a row of dates that stretch over a series of months. I want to colour anything within the range of B6-ZZ6 that falls between a specific range of dates (between start date and finish date) and colour it a green if Sheet 2 cell C6 is <30,  amber if >=30 and <40 and red if >40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment you just want to color code a calendar range depending on another value.

Lets assume you have your Source data like this on Sheet2
[image: Source Data]

And you want to Make a calendar here on Sheet1 with the color coding:
[image: Blank Calendar]

Create a rule for your calendar range `C2:ZZ6`
And use the formula

```
=AND(SHeet2!$B2>40, C$1>=SHeet2!$B2, C$1<SHeet2!$D2)
```

To color red.
No need to use `INDIRECT()` when you can use relative and absolute referencing.
Now just copy the formula with the other thresholds for Orange and Green.

Your output will look like this:
[image: Result]

Comment: I'm sure that I tried it this way before to no success, but this is working perfectly. Thank you for your input Robin, much appreciated